# Why can Entity Framework code connect to SQL express in IIS Express but not on IIS?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, iis, entity-framework-core, iis-express

I have a .Net core application that uses Entity Framework and SQL express running all running on the same machine.In debug mode from within Visual Studio 2019, i.e. IIS Express, I can read/write to the database no problem.

However, when I deploy to IIS also running on the same machine, any View which has a controller using Entity Framework returns a 404.

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

I'm assuming it's a privilages issue but using Trusted_Connection I'm not sure which account needs the privileges. Is it the admin account in windows 10? Do I need a special user account for ISS?

When I take away any code that uses EF, the 404 disappears so I'm certain it's a SQL server related issue.

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: When you're running in debug mode, IIS Express will be running under *your* credentials. When running under the service, it'll be running under the Service Accounts Credentials. As you're using a Trusted Connection, it appears you haven't given the IIS Servcie Account the correct permissions on your SQL Server Express instance.

Comment: I would first focus on why you return 404 when unable to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: I just created a new account in SQL express and gave it the same privileges as  my windows login. I changed the connection string to "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=MidasDB_Schema9;User Id=myuser;Password=mypw" and it all worked fine.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Basic differences you should learn.

Comment: As far as I know, if you hosted the application on IIS, it will use the application pool identity's credentials to access the sqlexpress. If you want to let the application access the sqlexpress directly. You should add the application pool identity account into the sqlexpress or modify the application pool identity account to another account which could access the sqlexpress